# Why does the medial hypothalamus cause affective aggression while it causes the release of serotonin?

Tags: neuroscience

Since aggression is inversely related to serotonin, why does activation of the medial hypothalamus, which sends axons to the serotonin-releasing PAG, cause affective aggression? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help to provide sources referencing the claims made in your post about serotonin, the medial hypothalamus, and aggression.